# How to use custom Oozie EL function read HDFS file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, el, oozie

Is it possible to write an EL function to read HDFS file in oozie

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write any EL function you like, see [this blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-write-an-el-function-in-apache-oozie/) for  instructions.