# Oozie - Dealing w/ 4-4-4 Calendar

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

We have a data source that is scheduled based on a 4-4-4 calendar (aka every 4 weeks).

We are looking to use coordinators and trigger file to notice the data arrival. I'd like to organize the folder structures based on yyyy/period_id (there are 13 periods in a year). We have 3 data feeds per period and each will arrive staggered over 3-4 days...so using mmdd is not ideal.

For example, the calendar would look as follows.

Start Date Jan 16

End Date Dec 18

- Jan 16 Instance 1 Path: 2017/1/*
- Feb 13 Instance 2
- Mar 13 Instance 3
- Apr 10 Instance 4
- May 8 Instance 5
- Jun 5 Instance 6
- Jul 3 Instance 7
- Jul 31 Instance 8
- Aug 28 Instance 9
- Sep 25 Instance 10
- Oct 23 Instance 11
- Nov 20 Instance 12
- Dec 18 Instance 13 Path: 2017/13/*

Is there a function in OOzie language that would allow to return the incremental instantiation # for the oozie coordinators?

I.e, the first job execution in July would return 7 and the 2nd job execution in July would return 8

Am i looking at this the wrong way? Another option would be to have a script lookup a value in a table for a date range and return the period ID which would be a bit more complex

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the question about whether there is an Oozie EL function that returns the instance number of a coordinator instance is: no, not to my knowledge.

It's possible that you could write a custom EL function to do a date calculation (see the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748214/how-to-use-custom-oozie-el-function-read-hdfs-file)) which returns a period number based on the current day of year.

However, I've found that the options for triggering Oozie coordinators are somewhat limited, so if you find that you're spending more time trying to figure out ways to work around Oozie's limitations, you might need to ask yourself if it's the right tool for the job.